# SQL Query Early/Late dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create an SQL view, based on results from the earliest and latest dates.  I am aware of the min and max functions but I've not been able to implement it correctly.  So far I have:

```
select distinct
name,
study,
group,
ROUND (TLength * POWER (TWidth, 2) * 0.000523, 3) as Volume,
firstDate as firstDate,
lastDate as lastDate
from
(select
name,
study,
group,
min(operation_time) firstDate,
max(operation_time) lastDate,
MAX(DECODE (ACTIVITY,'length', RESULT_VALUE, NULL)) TLength,
MAX(DECODE (ACTIVITY,'width', RESULT_VALUE,NULL)) TWidth
from mx_all_data_vw
where mx_all_data_vw.study_name like '%MT%' 
group by name, group study);
```

This gives me a single row for either the earliest or latest date, and two columns with earliest and latest dates.

I want 2 rows, that has a row containing all data for earliest date and another containing all data for latest date, rather than two columns seperating the early and late dates.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified for readability:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  mx_all_data_vw.*,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, study, "group" ORDER BY operation_time) rna,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, study, "group" ORDER BY operation_time DESC) rnd,
                DECODE(activity, 'length', result_value, NULL) AS TLength,
                DECODE(activity, 'width', result_value, NULL) AS TWidth
        FROM    mx_all_data_vw
        WHERE   mx_all_data_vw.study_name like '%MT%'
        )
WHERE   1 IN (rna, rnd)
```

Add the computed expressions instead of `*`.

Comment: Thanks, that works really well, except for the Decode parts above.  Basically I have a column called Activity, that I wish to obtain length and width from to have their own columns?

Comment: @Quassnio, thanks, but I now get an error saying 'not a single-group group function' any ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Darren: did you add the `OVER ()` part to the `MAX` functions?

Comment: Soooo close.  It's working well, apart from the pivot value.  I'm copying my bosses code, where he has used MAX(DECODE, but the values are returning as the maximum for each row.  How can I pivot so it returns the actual value of length and width for each date, for example, rather than the max value.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Quassnoi, yes I have added the OVER part.  Thanks

Comment: Have figured it out @Quassnoi, I have added an additional Partition to operation_time for the decode functions.  Thanks for all your help.